# How does the prototype pattern solve the abstract factory pattern issue with many product family?

Tags: design-patterns, abstract-factory

In *Design Patterns Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software*, it states that one of the issues in the
Abstract factory pattern is the following:

> 4. Supporting new kinds of products is difficult. Extending abstract factories to produce new kinds of
>    Products isn't easy. That's because the AbstractFactory interface fixes the set of products that can be
>    created. Supporting new kinds of products requires extending the factory interface, which involves changing
>    the AbstractFactory class and all of its subclasses. We discuss one solution to this problem in the
>    Implementation section.

And in the implementation section:

> If many product families are possible, the concrete factory can be imple- mented using the Prototype (117)
> pattern. The concrete factory is initialized with a prototypical instance of each product in the family, and
> it creates a new product by cloning its prototype. The Prototype-based approach eliminates the need for a new
> concrete factory class for each new product family.

I don't think I got it. How would a prototype implementation which —from my understanding— makes clonable
objects which have the very same properties, solve this issue?

Comment: The two quoted paragraphs are talking about different things. The first paragraph is about supporting more products. The second paragraph is about supporting more families. When the first paragraph states, "_We discuss one solution to this problem in the Implementation section_" it is not referring to the second paragraph.

Comment: So the question is, which problem/solution are you asking about: supporting more products, or supporting more families?

Comment: I think the question here is about supporting more number of products. For abstract-factory, if we try to add more number of products. Ultimately, we end up implementing in all Concrete Factory even though if that Factory class required it or not. In abstract-factory is it violating ISP ?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but I think that's what they mean...

With the abstract factory we have a **concrete factory per family**:

[image]

With the prototypes, we have a **single concrete factory**, configured with component prototypes of the given family:

e.g.

```java
UIComponentFactory windowsComponentFactory = new UIComponentFactory(
    new WindowsDropdownComponent(), new WindowsTextboxComponent()
);

UIComponentFactory macComponentFactory = new UIComponentFactory(
    new MacDropdownComponent(), new MacTextboxComponent()
);
```

[image]